# Get some error reason when upgrade elasticsearch 2.x to elasticsearch 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I have problem in query when upgrade elasticsearch 2.x to elasticsearch 5.0

The query is :

```
"query": {
  "function_score": {
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "dis_max": {
            "queries": [{
              "match_phrase": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "keyword",
                  "slop": 3
                }
              }
            }, {
              "match_phrase": {
                "content": {
                  "query": "keyword",
                  "slop": 3
                }
              }
            }],
            "tie_breaker": 0.3
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [{
              "bool": {
                "must": [{
                  "type": {
                    "value": "product"
                  }
                }, {
                  "term": {
                    "is_deleted": false
                  }
                }]
              }
            }, {
              "bool": {
                "must": [{
                  "type": {
                    "value": "service"
                  }
                }, {
                  "term": {
                    "is_deleted": false
                  }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "functions": [{
      "script_score": {
        "script": "doc['_type'].value == 'product' ? _score * 15 : (doc['_type'].value == 'service' ? _score * 10 : _score)",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

I get the reason like this :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
        "line" : 6,
        "col" : 76
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
    "line" : 6,
    "col" : 76
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I have research, in elasticsearch 5.0 `filtered` has been depracted and I should change to `bool`. I try to change it but i get reason error look like 'script_score query does not support [lang]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query to this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "dis_max": {
              "queries": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "title": {
                      "query": "keyword",
                      "slop": 3
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "content": {
                      "query": "keyword",
                      "slop": 3
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "tie_breaker": 0.3
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "product"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "is_deleted": false
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "service"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "is_deleted": false
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['_type'].value == 'product' ? _score * 15 : (doc['_type'].value == 'service' ? _score * 10 : _score)",
              "lang": "groovy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working.. I think I have mistake when replace `filtered` to `bool`

Comment: No, the `script_score` also needed some tweaking

Comment: Yes, I miss that, you save my times :), wait in minutes